# I get an UnhandledPromiseRejection with Express middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, middleware

I'm trying to check if a user is logged in before trying to access the `addContact` endpoint.

```
var isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
   if(req.session.user)
       next();

   //unauthorized
   res.status(401).send('Please log in.');
};
```

The post route `addContact` looks like this and I'm using the `isLoggedIn` middleware to check if a user signed in before adding.

```
app.post('/addContact', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {

   //if Mongo database is not started
   if(mongoose.connection.readyState !== 1) {
       res.send(`We're sorry. We are having trouble connecting. Try again later`);
       return;
   }

   var contact = new Contact({
       _userId: req.session.user.id,
       name: req.body.name,
       phone_number: req.body.phone_number,
       email: req.body.email
   });

   console.log('adding contact from session', req.session.user);

   contact.save().then((c) => {
       res.send(`${contact.name} was added succesfully.`);
   }).catch((e) => {
       res.send(e);
   });

});
```

'Adding contact from session:' is being logged to the console with the right session id `req.session.user`. But once it tries to `save()` the new contact, I am getting the following error

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

And the response that is being sent says 'Please log in' which is specified in the middleware `isLoggedIn`.

Can somebody tell me why is this happening? I'm trying not to duplicate questions but I can't find a solution. Thanks

Comment: `res.status(401).send('Please log in.');` always executes. no matter if your user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return` after your call to `next`:

```
var isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
   if(req.session.user) {
       next();
       return;
    }

   //unauthorized
   res.status(401).send('Please log in.');
};
```

And actually better yet:

```
var isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
   if (!req.session.user) {
       const err = new Error('Please login')
       err.status = 401
       throw err
    }

   next()
};
```

Then have actual error handler middleware:

```
/**
 * Show useful information to client in development.
 */
exports.development = (err, req, res, next) => {
  err.stack = err.stack || ''
  const status = err.status || 500

  res.status(status).json({
    status,
    error
  })
}

/**
 * Do not show errors in production.
 */
exports.production = (err, req, res, next) => {
  if (err.stack) {
    delete err.stack
  }

  err.message = err.messsage || 'oops'
  err.status = err.status || 500

  res.status(err.status).json({
    status: err.status,
    error: {
      message: err.message
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is in this snippet:

```
if(req.session.user)
       next();

   //unauthorized
   res.status(401).send('Please log in.');
```

The error **Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client** in essence means you're trying to respond to the HTTP Request more than once, which express doesn't let you do. The call to `next()` means another middleware further down is setting a response, then when you call `res.status(401)` you're trying to set the response again.

Long story short you should just do an early return like this:

```
var isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
   if(req.session.user)
       return next(); // note we exit the middleware here!

   //unauthorized
   res.status(401).send('Please log in.');
};
```